# Log is not getting printed for Extent Test Manager reports

Tags: selenium, extentreports

I am using extent test manager reports but while the reports are generated there are no step name column added in the reports that is generated

I have used the below method:

```
ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS,"Click on the \"Add Alarm Group\" button.","'Add Alarm Group' should be clickable.");
```

Issue is that the 2nd parameter in the .log is not getting printed that is the step name.

Comment: Try to send single string instead of two strings. Replace comma with "+" and try again.

Comment: @Kuldeep i have to print Stepname and details that's why i passed two parameters with one parameter it works fine !!!!!! 
 ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS,StepName:" ", Details," ")

Comment: You can print Stepname and details also. Just send them as concatenated string like :  
`ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS,"StepName:"+ "Details"+ "Step 1") `

Comment: It print in the same line i have to print in a separate column. and i am using the inbuild method of ExtendTestClass which accept 3 parameter,below is the method !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                                   public void log(LogStatus logStatus, String stepName, String details) {

    }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version 3 of Extent Reports you can actually use the Markups to achieve a better reporting, please find below the code

```
String stepName = "Click on the \"Add Alarm Group\" button.";
String description = "'Add Alarm Group' should be clickable.";

String code = "Step Name: " + stepName + "\nDescription: " + 
description;
Markup m = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(code);
t1.pass(m);
```